# Cache MySQL connection in rails. NO activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mysql2

I'm working on a rails app with `mongodb`, `mongoid` as ORM. I am not using `activerecord` in this project. I do need however to connect to a couple of MySQL dbs to get and write some data. I have a total of 3 queries that I need to execute on these dbs.

I feel like for what I need to do, there's no reason to include `activerecord` as it would be overkill.

The problem is that every time I need to get data from the MySQL db, I need to open a new connection to the server and close it after a couple of seconds. These queries are frequent, every 5 seconds. Is there any way to store a MySQL connection and reuse that instead of closing and reopening? I find it to be less overhead. Also, I'd like to have a way to re-open a connection if for some reason it should close unexpectedly. I remember there was a fix some time ago about "`MySQL server has gone away`" error and I think this will happen if I don't use `activerecord`.